# Is possible to use setters when Gson deserializes a JSON?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

Is there any way the set methods of a given class, are used when using Gson's `fromJson` method?

I would like to do this because for every `String` global variable of the target class a trim is made.

Is there any GSON API annotation for this?

I am aware that GSON provides the ability to write custom serializers/deserializers but I would like to know if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented a `JsonDeserializer<String>` and registered it on `GsonBuilder`. So, to all String fields received, Gson will use my `StringGsonTypeAdapter` to deserialize the value.

Below is my code:

```
import static net.hugonardo.java.commons.text.StringUtils.normalizeSpace;
import static net.hugonardo.java.commons.text.StringUtils.trimToNull;

final class StringGsonTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private static final StringGsonTypeAdapter INSTANCE = new StringGsonTypeAdapter();

    static StringGsonTypeAdapter instance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, 
        JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return normalizeSpace(trimToNull(jsonElement.getAsString()));
    }
}
```

...and my GsonBuilder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, StringGsonTypeAdapter.instance())
    .create())
```

Answer (score 16):

**No**, there is not. Gson works mainly by reflection on instance fields. So if you do not plan to move to Jackson that has this feature I think you cannot have a general way to call your setters. So there's no annotation for that.

**BUT**

to achieve your specific need you could:

1. write your own custom [TypeAdapter](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) or
2. create a constructor that has the string you intend to trim and create a custom [InstanceCreator](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) or
3. parse your JSON as [JsonObject](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html), do some processing of the strings and then use that object as source for parsing into your class.

I can provide you with more hints as long as you post some code or give information about your data/JSON.