# Gson custom deserialization but only one field

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm receiving from API long json, e.g.:

```
{
  "field1": "val1",
  "field2": "val2",
  ...
  "SOME_FIELD": "   ABC   ",
  ...
  "fieldx": "valx"
}
```

I would like to deserialize it with Gson. Everything works fine but field's "SOME_FIELD" value is always with annoying spaces. I would like to trim() this field value (API can't be changed). I know I can use JsonDeserializer but then I have to manually read all fields. Is it possible to edit only one interesing field while deserializing but use auto deserialization for rest of them?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660334/is-possible-to-use-setters-when-gson-deserializes-a-json) might help you... Another option would be to use a getter whenever you retrieve the value from the object.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am writing a Demo Class to Convert JSON to a class by ignoring some of the non-used property embedded in `JSON`.

Here I have used `ObjectMapper` Class to deserialize the `JSONObject` as an `Object`.

```
 //configuration to enables us to ignore non-used Unknow Properties.
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

> Test Class (Code To Convert a Json into a Class Object).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws JsonProcessingException 
     * @throws JsonMappingException 
     * @throws JsonParseException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        Test o = new Test();
        o.GetJsonAsObject(o.putJson());

    }

//function to generate a json for demo Program.
    private String putJson() throws JsonProcessingException{
        HashMap<String, String> v_Obj = new HashMap<>();
        v_Obj.put("field1", "Vikrant");
        v_Obj.put("field2", "Kashyap");
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(v_Obj); // change the HashMap as JSONString
    }

   //function to Convert a json Object in Class Object for demo Program.
    private void GetJsonAsObject(String value) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        Test1 obj = mapper.readValue(value, Test1.class);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

}
```

> Test1.java (Conversion POJO Class)

```
class Test1{

    private String field1;

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.field1.toString();
}
```

}

Read Comment Properly.. hope you got the concept .

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your post but I'm using Gson and changing it to Jackson would take too much time (whole project is pretty big and gson is used in many places).

Comment: have your tried this link  >> http://www.baeldung.com/gson-deserialization-guide